# Getting error insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, myetherwallet, etherscan

I have almost searched all of duplicate questions but not getting any help.
Can someone please point out what is wrong why I'm getting error `insufficient funds for gas * price + value`, I double check and I have enough ether in my test account.

Some console output:

```
    console.log('web3 version:'+ web3.version);
    web3.eth.net.getId(function(err, res){
        console.log("Net: "+res);
    });
    web3.eth.net.getNetworkType(function(err, res){
            console.log("getNetworkType: "+res);
    });
    web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function(error, result){
        console.log("Block Number: "+result);
   });


    web3 version:1.0.0-beta.34
    Block Number: 3085927
    291 Net: 3
    getNetworkType: ropsten
```

My Simple Web Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://example.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/js/web3.js-1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendTrans();">Send Trans</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://45:158:654:7:8545'));


function sendTrans(){
    // ShahzadTestCoin contract ABI Array
var abiArray =[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"fundsWallet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"version","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"unitsOneEthCanBuy","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalEthInWei","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_extraData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"approveAndCall","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}];

// Who holds the token now?
var myAddress = "0x429C4474c5914a28063e2C37cA23bb4aF9ef0728"; //5.978318602 Ether//https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x429C4474c5914a28063e2C37cA23bb4aF9ef0728

// Who are we trying to send this token to?
var destAddress = "0x0346d2e50E29065b3b3c73B878FaFDcEb8Ee13f0"; //4.999873784 Ether//https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0346d2e50E29065b3b3c73B878FaFDcEb8Ee13f0


// ShahzadTestCoin Token (STC)
// The address of the contract
var contractAddress = "0xc61BEC3497e549b9fA58AE79a5a573E064fe3311";//https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc61bec3497e549b9fa58ae79a5a573e064fe3311
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress);
myContract.options.from = myAddress;

var privateKey = 'a369264ebe211xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

var transactionObject = {
    from: myAddress,
    to: contractAddress,
    value: '0x0', 
    data: myContract.methods.transfer(destAddress, 5).encodeABI(),
    chainId: 3
};


web3.eth.getGasPrice(function(err, getGasPrice){

    if(!err){
        console.log("getGasPrice: "+getGasPrice);
        transactionObject.gasPrice = getGasPrice;

        web3.eth.estimateGas(transactionObject, function(err, estimateGas){
            console.log("estimateGas  err: "+err);
            console.log("estimateGas  res: "+estimateGas);

            transactionObject.gas = estimateGas;

            web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transactionObject, privateKey , function(err, signed){


            console.log("signTransaction err: "+err);

            if(!err){
                console.log("signTransaction signed: "+signed.rawTransaction);

                web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction, function(err, res){
                    console.log("sendSignedTransaction  err: "+err);
                    if(!err){
                        console.log("sendSignedTransaction  res: "+res);
                    }
                });
            }
            });
        });
    }
});

}

</scrip>
</body>
</html>
```

Contract Source Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Token {

    /// @return total amount of tokens
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply) {}

    /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
    /// @return The balance
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    /// @param _from The address of the sender
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_addr` to spend `_value` tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @param _value The amount of wei to be approved for transfer
    /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {}

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}

contract StandardToken is Token {

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
        //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
        //Replace the if with this one instead.
        //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
        //if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
      return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
}

contract ShahzadTestCoin is StandardToken { // CHANGE THIS. Update the contract name.

    /* Public variables of the token */

    /*
    NOTE:
    The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
    They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
    Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
    */
    string public name;                   // Token Name
    uint8 public decimals;                // How many decimals to show. To be standard complicant keep it 18
    string public symbol;                 // An identifier: eg SBX, XPR etc..
    string public version = 'H1.0'; 
    uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy;     // How many units of your coin can be bought by 1 ETH?
    uint256 public totalEthInWei;         // WEI is the smallest unit of ETH (the equivalent of cent in USD or satoshi in BTC). We'll store the total ETH raised via our ICO here.  
    address public fundsWallet;           // Where should the raised ETH go?

    // This is a constructor function 
    // which means the following function name has to match the contract name declared above
    function ShahzadTestCoin() {
        balances[msg.sender] = 1000000000000000000000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens. This is set to 1000 for example. If you want your initial tokens to be X and your decimal is 5, set this value to X * 100000. (CHANGE THIS)
        totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000;                        // Update total supply (1000 for example) (CHANGE THIS)
        name = "ShahzadTestCoin";                                   // Set the name for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        decimals = 18;                                               // Amount of decimals for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        symbol = "STCN";                                             // Set the symbol for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        unitsOneEthCanBuy = 10;                                      // Set the price of your token for the ICO (CHANGE THIS)
        fundsWallet = msg.sender;                                    // The owner of the contract gets ETH
    }

    function() payable{
        totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value;
        uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy;
        require(balances[fundsWallet] >= amount);

        balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;

        Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, amount); // Broadcast a message to the blockchain

        //Transfer ether to fundsWallet
        fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);                               
    }

    /* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
        //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
        //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
        if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `gas` and `gasPrice`? Have you tried including a leading `0x` in the private key? My guess would be that somehow the transaction is being sent "from" the wrong account (which would mean something is wrong with the private key).

Comment: @smarx you save my life :) I included `0x` in front of private key and now it is working, thanks man... estimate Gas is  `36210`, could you please put a answer with detail what is `0x` and where should I need to use it? should I include it in beginning of transfer tokens?

Comment: I can see my transaction now at ropsten network as well :)

Comment: One thing more when I send these tokens with myetherwallet, there is a field `Gas Limit`, should I include `gasLimit` option in my transaction object or `gas` option is okay ?

Comment: Who will pay gas price? token sender or token receiver?

Comment: Added an answer. Gas is always paid by the account that makes the transaction. So the token sender, in this case.

Comment: `gas` and `gasLimit` are just aliases for each other. You can use either one.

Comment: Great all is fine now :) and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the comments on the question, you need to add a `0x` to the beginning of your private key. `web3.js` often requires this prefix so it knows the string you're supplying is a hexadecimal representation of a byte sequence (like a private key).

Comment: Wow! Thank you thank you for that simple tidbit. That '0x' cost me an hour or so and a lot of searching for solutions.